# How to initialize ICollections on new entities so items are automatically added to the change tracker

Tags: entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I believe that if you load a database object with a linq or .Find command that sub collections that were also included in the call will automatically add items to the changetracker and save them:

```
entity.Children.Add(entityChild);
```

This would add it to the change tracker for the attached entity just fine.

If however you're creating a new entity and on constructor you set the ICollection to a new HashSet() it doesn't add to the change tracker when you do the Children.Add(entityChild) line.

How do you initialize ICollections for new objects so that when Add to the child it adds it to the change tracker?

And I thought it was supposed to add all children that are new to the change tracker too if you added the parent (i.e. create the parent, add the children then add the parent to the DbSet should add the children to the change tracker too right?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new instance of an entity type with change tracking enabled, you need to use the [Create method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696539.aspx) on DbSet.

You can also manually kick-off change detection by calling the [DetectChanges method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbchangetracker.detectchanges.aspx) on `DbContext.ChangeTracker`.

Finally, if you want to add a lot of code to your POCO classes, you can look at the code that gets generated by the [self-tracking entities template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a3ac10a5-9365-4096-bb58-d9a1ba71db8f). This is effectively the same code that EF uses for objects that are returned when querying the database.

Comment: The problem with that is that it appears that you can only do it from the DbContext which needs to be known and thus passed for every constructor etc. (as far as I can tell)  Is there not a way to set these up in the constructor of the object without that?

Comment: @user1515307 Updated my answer with a few other approaches you may want to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I was hoping for a pretty solution but I guess that isn't in the cards. Oh well.